# Getting rid of warning: integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion] with working code

Tags: c, pointers

I am working on a tiny bit of code that will take in a text document and "encode" it by shifting all chars by 5 (ascii).

The code is working, but I am getting an error and was wondering how I would get rid of it.

I am getting this warning:

```
warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
            char new_ch = *ch + 5;
```

The relevant portion of my code is :

```
        char *ch[0];
        // Reads and writes output
        while (read(old_file, current_char, 1) == 1) {
           char new_ch = *ch + 5;
           write(new_file, &new_ch, 1);
        }
```

Comment: `char *ch[0];`. Please show how `ch` is used. Looks like that declaration is wrong and should be `char ch;`. But can't tell for sure since the code shown is incomplete.

Comment: If your bogous code appears to work as you expect you should google "c undefined behaviour"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with `ch`; it's an array of pointers.

If you are reading one char at a time, you would instead need:

```
char ch;
```

and make your `read` calls with:

```
if (read(fd, &ch, 1) < 0) {
    /* error */
}
```

i.e. just like how you use `new_ch` when calling `write`:

```
    char ch;
    // Reads and writes output
    while (read(old_file, &ch, 1) == 1) {
       char new_ch = ch + 5;
       write(new_file, &new_ch, 1);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

C doesn't have dynamic arrays, you attempt to create an array of zero elements (which is invalid) where each element is a *pointer*.

And this array of pointers is what leads to your error as the expression `*ch` is the same as `ch[0]`, which is a pointer. Adding `5` to that pointer will just make it point a little further on in memory but it's still a pointer. Then you assign this pointer (`ch[0] + 5`) to the single `char` variable `new_ch`.

So there are multiple problems in your code, but unfortunately only one of them seems to lead to a warning being generated by the compiler.

Exactly how to solve your problem and get rid of the warning depends on what you're really trying to do, but very likely you're supposed to make `ch` a single character, as in

```
char ch;
```

and then use a pointer to that (gotten by `&ch`) as the destination for the `read` call:

```
read(old_file, &ch, 1)
```

Then you could add `5` to that single character:

```
char new_ch = ch + 5;
```

and write it to the new file.

Answer (score 1):

`char *ch[0];` defines the array of pointers to char which has size 0. If you try to dereference it you will invoke the UB.

you need to

```
    char ch[some_size_larger_than_zero];
    // Reads and writes output
    while (read(old_file, current_char, 1) == 1) {
       char new_ch = *ch + 5;
       write(new_file, &new_ch, 1);
    }
```